# Radius Networks AltBeacon background power saving option

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am using the Radius Networks AltBeacon library and trying to utilise the background power saving feature for Android.

The documentation states that the background power saving defaults are for a 30 second scan to take place every 5 minutes. I have 3 beacons in 3 separate regions. I just tested the default battery saving settings and detected my first beacon at 11.01.

If I am understanding things correctly, nothing else should then be detected until at least 11.06 but I then walked within range of beacon number 2 and this was detected at 11.02 and then at 11.04 my third beacon was detected when I walked within range of that.

**Can anyone explain a bit more about how the power saving feature works?**

I am using Estimote beacons and testing on a Nexus 5.  My two lines  of code I use to set this up are:

```
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
```

thanks!

Comment: Ok, it appears to be working now as I would expect i.e. every 5 minutes.  I was using an older version of the library before.  Now I have the latest one.  And also, I may have been opening the app in foreground before which I suspect may have caused a scan to take place.  Anyway, now it seems to be working on a 5 minute cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in doubt, you can check to see if the library thinks it is in background mode by calling `beaconManager.getBetweenScanPeriod()` and seeing if you get the 5 minute default.

You can also learn more about how the library determines if the app is in the background by looking here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/powersave/BackgroundPowerSaver.java

Note that it tracks activities pausing and resuming.  It defines background mode as when no activities have resumed.

Glad to hear it is working for you now!